# Talend Studio Big data 6.0 third party libraries missing

Tags: bigdata, talend

I have installed **Talend Open Studio for Big Data 6.0**.

When I try to open Local Project, I am getting

> "Optional third party libraries(1) means you cannot configure the download location manually.

Also I am getting

> Required third party libraries(341).

I am selecting both and clicked on Finish button and restarted.  But, again and again I am getting same issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Select** both the mentioned option and **Select Install** after completion **Click on Finish** tab. It will work.